# Is there an api for YouTube Analytics?

Tags: api, analytics, youtube-api

On the Youtube analytics page it states that "YouTube Analytics reports are generated using the same data that users are used to seeing in Insight, and much more."

(http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=1728599&guide=1714169&page=guide.cs)

However there a couple of metrics shown in there that I haven't been able to find through the youtube api, such as retention (hot spots), monetizable views, impressions, etc.

My questions are:
Do I need a brand page to access there features? (I guess so)
Will those metrics be available through an api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on exactly the same issue. The basic answer is there is no API available yet, but I have been able to fudge a homebrew API using HTTPClient as a pretend browser.

A bit of firebugging got me these urls:

google.com/accounts/ClientLogin

youtube.com/signin?action_handle_signin=true&nomobiletemp=1&hl=en_US&next=%2F&pli=1&auth="+key

youtube.com/insight_proxy_csv?dim=DAY&ord=DAY&from=27122011&to=02012012&where=UN001&whatType=CHANNEL&whatId=userID

You'll have to play around and see what works for you but it is possible to extract the information programatically.

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been added in the 2.0 version of the YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_insight

Answer (score 1):

New [YouTube Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/index) was [announced](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/06/build-awesome-youtube-experiences-with.html) on June 27, 2012

Answer (score 0):

An experimental release of the YouTube Analytics API is now publicly available: http://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics